# How can I fix empty space on mobile HTML site?

Tags: html, css

My HTML website currently has a large empty space on the right side on mobile. The website is pumpkinchugger.github.io/rona20.live how can I get rid of this empty space? I currently have this in my CSS file, and I think it is causing this problem?

```
@media all and (max-width:991px){
    .row{
        flex-direction:column;
    }

    .container--wrap{
        width: 98vw!important; 
    }
}
```

Is the max width the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overflow happens on the tradingView widget which set a fixed width of 500px. If you want a more proper fix for **The widget is not adapting to different screen sizes. What should I do?**, please refer to [Market Overview Widget FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/market-overview/).

For now, I recommend fixing the issue with the following CSS code by setting the maximum width of the widget chart to 100%.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  div.tradingview-widget-container__widget,
  div.tradingview-widget-container__widget > div:first-child,
  div.tradingview-widget-container__widget > div:first-child > iframe {
      max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was the widget causing the problem! Thanks so much!

Comment: @pumpkinchugger glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think max-width is the problem here. Upon inspecting the page, i removed the mentioned CSS, it did not change much and also, the spacing wasn't removed. When the width was set to 145% from 100%, it semeed to fit the page correctly